# Ordering and sorting in RESTful api

Tags: api, rest

I want to allow users to choose which property they would like to sort by then choose whether to order by ascending or descending.

For example, to sort based on the title and by descending order you would make a call to the api like so:

```
api/blogs?sortBy=title&orderBy=desc
```

Is this the best way to go about doing this?

I can't find anything useful online and most posts explain that sort by and order by are basically the same thing.

What are peoples opinions on this?

Comment: Another way is just one string variable that you parse that accepts something like `sort='title asc, year desc'`. That way you can specify multiple fields with specific order per field.

Comment: I think this is a good approach. These parameters are in general optional, and actually ordering is out of the scope of RESTfulness. You should provide a default sorting that you allow overriding over parameters. As long as this is GET, it is actually the simplest way also. However, even if common, you are not bound to this method. For others, you could pass complex structure in the body that would give you more flexibility if needed.

Comment: @Silvermind Seems very complex for what I want to achieve. However, it is a good idea.

Comment: It is not that complex. Split by comma, then split each by space. You don't have fields with spaces or comma, so these are easily verified. And while your at it, write an extension method for it. ;)

Comment: @ZorgoZ Thank you, currently there is no default for sorting. Infact, if the sort by isn't provided then it won't sort anything.  How complex could this get?

Comment: @KTOV Well, your scenario probably has a naturally logical ordering. Anyway, if you use pagination too, you should consider returning two things in the result: the actual result set and a descriptor which contains the applied ordering and pagination details. You can still use this approach even without pagination, and just for ordering.

Answer (score 3):

There is not the "best" way to do that. For any API, basically it's more important to have consistency, follow the same strategy across the endpoints and be flexible enough to future improvements.

So, we have some options. For example, if you need to order by `title` with `DESC` and by `author` with `ASC`, you can choose:

```
/api/blogs?sort=-title,+author

/api/blogs?sort=desc(title),asc(author)
 
/api/blogs?sort=title:desc,author:asc
```

Some people use the format used in your example. But it's have the limitation to not be flexible enough to allow the sort by multiple fields, because `sort` and `order` are separated.

Comment: In a REST ecosystem servers will provide clients with all the possible links a client may interact with based on the current state of the resource the client requested last. If so, it is more a matter of creating meaningful link relation names rather than over-engineered URIs to teach clients on what they can do next. As such, the characters that form a URI are not of importance in a REST architecture. Such relation names should follow either standardized (IANA) names or follow an extension approach as explained in RFC 8288 (Web Linking)

Answer (score 1):

This is a very good way of doing it.

Look at smaller retail websites, they often use Get, so people can bookmark their search and sorting.

If you want multi-column sorting, just use a separator-character.